# Build a solution file for .Net Console application by files running on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, nuget, solution

I have a .Net application running on the IIS and I need to generate the solution file for it in Visual Studio 2017! So I copied the file to my local computer and on VS I selected 
"Project from Existing code" but when I want to build I get error

"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0111 Type 'Default2' already defines a member called 'Page_Init' with the same parameter types Risk"

another error is

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'CommFunc.ValidTime' and 'CommFunc.ValidTime'
"
and I get bunch of other errors.

I added all the references and NuGet packages which it needed. Any Idea how Can I build the solution file? is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Better off getting a hold of the original solution and opening that up.

Comment: unfortunately that does not exist! so not going back

Comment: Can I ask why doesn't it exist? How did it get lost?

Comment: Like others commented, even with slightest hope you should attempt to grab the original code. If that's not available and you only have the binaries, then "Project from **Existing code**" won't help you much as you don't have the actual code. Reverse engineering can only be done on a case-by-case manner and is too broad to discuss as a general question here (without you sharing the binaries with the whole world).